# Current limiter for fixed voltage output

Tags: current

I need to design a current limiter for a circuit. I haven't started to design it so I cannot show the schematics, but I'll try to explain it.

It consists just in 2 light sensors. These sensors send a value to an MCU. The supply voltage is 12V but is lowered to 5V for the electronics. The important thing is here:

Depending on the values of the sensors (This corresponds to de programmable part of the MCU) I'll need to have a -1.5V, 0V or 1.5V output value. This is, -1.5V and 1.5V will supply the load, and 0V just won't do anything. The maximum Amperes value must be around 200mA or a bit lower.

So, I ask if you know any component-circuit that could suit this requirements.

**UPDATE --**

According to the comments, I'll update the post with few more data.

The functionality must be like, if sensor1 < sensor2 then output is -15V, and if sensor1 > sensor2 output 1.5V.

But I still have some things in the air that I need to define:

- I could use a voltage regulator to low the voltage from 5V to 1.5V, but then, I'll need to define how I generate the negative voltage.
- I need to set how the MCU tells if the output is negative or positive
- I need to define the current limiter. I found components like [this](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3092fb.pdf), but this one has reverse-voltage protection so maybe for this purpose is not the best option

Comment: Do I get it right, that you need to limit the absolute value of current on -1.5V to +1.5V rail?

Comment: You should try and formulate your exact requirements. If incident light is above X then output is Y. If incident light is below Z then output is -Y etc..

Comment: @Dzarda the output will be -1,5V or 1,5V. In booth cases, the current will be something like 100mA. But to avoid peaks, I need to set the current limit to 200mA for example.

Comment: @Andy aka I haven't define the requirements yet, but yes, it would be something like if sensor1<sensor2 then output 1,5V, and if sensor1>sensor2 then output -1,5V

Comment: Where does the current for that +/- 1.5 V come from? You did not mention a negative supply, do you have to create a negative voltage just for this purpose? And would a relay be appropriate for the switching?

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen I'm still not sure on how to do it. I supply the MCU with 5V. The MCU is the one that sets if the output is positive or negative, I can use a voltage regulator as the one  I use to convert from 12V to 5V, to pass from 5V to 1,5V. But I still have few things to define, as, how to create that negative voltage, how do the MCU tell to be positive or negative, and how to limit the current.

Comment: I've updated the post defining few requirements

Comment: Add a negative voltage generator and use comparators - get rid of the MCU - it isn't bringing anything to the party as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Andy aka I cannot get rid of the MCU. Here I explained in a simple way, but the MCU is the one that proceses de data from the light sensors and via an HMI gives the user the option to define manually the value. The final purpose is to darken or clear a screen. 1,5V clears it and -1,5V darkes it, the MCU gives the chance to select intermediate states

Comment: What do you need that +/- 1.5V for? There might be an easier way to get the effect you want.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen, as I said, the 1,5V make the screen darken, and the -1,5V makes it clear.

Comment: I found this one: http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX660.pdf , it inverts the input voltage from positive to negative, limiting the current to 100mA. What do you think about it?

Comment: Can you drive your load with full bridge, e. g. +1,5 V on 'negative' load rail, instead of generating negative voltage? This could simplify your task a lot.

Comment: @Vovanium Do you refer to an H bridge? I'll think about the posibility of doing it that way. Could you provide an example of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it suitable your needs, you may use H-bridge to power your load. Here's schematic sketch to give yu idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwIUJb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's current limited voltage source (V, I, R1, Q1-Q4) which powers H-bridge of four MOSFETs, and load R2. (Supposed voltage drop across MOSFETS is negligible).

This current limited source consist of current mirror (as current limiter) with emitter follower (as voltage limiter), but you may use any other type you want.